# JavaScript Algorithm: Is there a better way to get the anomaly from a sorted array where the difference between any two consecutive is 1

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search

I have a sorted array where the difference between any two consecutive is 1 except for one number, and the function is going to return the index of the number. For example, `[100, 101, 102, 107]`, it is going to return `3`. Here is my attempt.

```js
const sortedArray =  [100, 101, 102, 107]

function getAnomaly(sortedArray) {
    const index = sortedArray.findIndex((val, index, self) => {
        return val + 1 !== (self[index + 1] ?? val + 1)
    })
    
    return index === -1 ? -1 : index + 1
}

getAnomaly(sortedArray)
```

It takes `O(n)` to scan the array and find the number. I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do it given the array is sorted? But I am not sure exactly how.

Comment: @NicholasTower I think there may be a log(n) solution what works by recursively dividing the array in half, and seeing which half has the start and ending values that aren't expected from incrementing values.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, i realized after i posted that. And i am indeed surprised :) Writing up a more detailed answer, unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: There probably are small ways to improve it to not have look ups, but doubt anything would have huge gains in performance

Comment: The OP even hinted at this by using the `binary-search` tag. So why didn't he try that kind of solution?

Comment: @Bamar: I think that would work if there is one unexpected *jump* in the sequential value, e.g. `[100, 101, 102, 107, 108, 109, ...]`.  But if there's a single anomalous *value*, e.g. `[100, 101, 102, 107, 104, 105, 106, ...]`, then I don't see how a binary search would uncover it any faster than a scan.  I was assuming the latter.  Were you assuming the former?  And if not, can you explain how it might work?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Arrays given is in sorted format.

Comment: @nice_dev: Sorry, I don't follow.  The OP had a change at the fourth and last element.  My two have a change at the fourth element, but then carry on differently afterward.  What are you saying?

Comment: @ScottSauyet `[100, 101, 102, 107, 104, 105, 106, ...]` is not in a sorted state. The _whole_ given array  to the function `getAnomaly` is already sorted. Also, OP states _difference between any two consecutive is 1 except for one number_ but your example will have more than 1 which also doesn't satisfy the constraints. Hence, it is an invalid testcase.

Comment: @nice_dev: If "except for one number" applies only to the difference of one then that's my first case.  If it also applies to "sorted", then it we're in my second.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes your first case is valid but not the second one.

Comment: @nice_dev: Well that was my question for the OP, I guess, although really I was asking if Bamar had some sensible way to handle the second one.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Hmm.. For the second case of an unsorted one, there could be multiple correct answers when scanned.

Comment: @nice_dev: I don't think so.  We could answer it by asking, "which index could we remove so that the remainder is an integer range?"  Things fall down when there are only two elements, but that's true in the other scenario as well... as either one could be removed as anomalous.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes, true.

Comment: what about values at start or end?

Comment: @NinaScholz: I think that assuming we are looking for a single *jump*, we can't see that at the beginning.  But at the end it should be obvious.  If we are looking for a single anomalous *value*, as long as there are more than two values, we can capture either of them.  With only two values, the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can make it more efficient since the array given to function `getAnomaly` is already sorted and the answer is the same as you have already added the tag, that is *binary search*.

For every mid value you get in the array, if it equals it's `index + the lowest value`, you can safely conclude that all the elements before it are arranged correctly with a consecutive difference of 1 and the left half can be ignored.

If it is arranged correctly, answer lies in the right side of the array. If not, record the index and move towards the left.

**Note** that the moment the alignment breaks, you can't quickly return the
index since the `sortedArray[ mid ]` can be arranged correctly with it's neighbours and some number to it's left can be the culprit for the gap.

**Snippet:**

```js
const sortedArray =  [100, 101, 102, 107];

function getAnomaly(sortedArray) {
    let low = 0, high = sortedArray.length - 1;
    let ans = -1;
    while(low <= high){
      let mid = low + ((high - low) >> 1);
      if(sortedArray[ mid ] === sortedArray[0] + mid){
        low = mid + 1;
      }else{
        ans = mid;
        high = mid - 1;
      }
    }
    return ans;
}

console.log(getAnomaly(sortedArray));
```

**Time Complexity:** `O(log(n))` since we divide the search space in the array each time by half.

**Space Complexity:** `O(1)`

Comment: Yes, this was my first case, discussed in the comments to the question.  I'm guessing that this is what the OP was looking for.  I don't see any good sub-`O(n)`solution for my second case.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes, sub - O(n) doesn't exist for your 2nd case. Linear scan is the way to go if the array is unsorted.

Comment: I was hoping Bamar had some nice trick I didn't know of for the case of an almost-entirely-sorted array.  I can't think of one, but there are plenty of cool tricks I've been unable to think of myself!

Comment: @ScottSauyet If by almost entirely sorted you mean pieces of the array sorted in itself and joined together, then maybe we can try an approach of jumping twice starting from the first element each time we find alignment and then stop when we don't and the linearly scan from the previous element. Unfortunately, the worst case for this would still be O(n).